# How to copy a product's attributes value to Manufacturer - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, manufacturer

I want to copy a product's attributes value to Manufacturer

e.g.
I have attribute CAR MANUFACTURER with values OPEL, TOYOTA, AUDI, BMW...
I need to copy values OPEL, TOYOTA, AUDI, BMW... to Manufacturer for each product.

Please help

Comment: Please explain your question in detail.

Comment: e.g.
I have attribute CAR MANUFACTURER with values OPEL, TOYOTA, AUDI, BMW...
I need to copy values OPEL, TOYOTA, AUDI, BMW... to Manufacturer for each product.